# Wait for the end of TWO asynchrounous functions before firing a third (jQuery Deferred ?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, deferred

I'm trying to understand jQuery's `Deferred`, but inspite of samples, I can't achieve what I want to do.

So, I'd like to call 2 functions asynchrounously, and, when BOTH are ended, call another one.

Here's my code

```
function1();
function2();

function3();
```

`function1()` and `function2()` make an ajax call to my ASP.NET application, and they perfectly work. They must be ended before `function3()` starts.

I'm reading and reading again [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) but function3() doens't wait for the end of the two others. Could you please provide my some sample in order to I understand `Deferred` ? I really need them to finish an important part of my project.

Thank you very much.

**BONUS QUESTION**

I've read about `.when` deferred... It is possible to write in some `<div>` element something like *function1() running*, then *function2() running* etc... ?

**UPDATE**

More details about `function1()` and `function2()` : They are very similar, here are they body :

```
function function1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url         :   "@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController")",
        contentType :   "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType    :   "json"
    }).done(function(data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            pushDatas(data[index]);
        })
    }).fail(function (result) {
        alert("function1failed");
    });
}

function pushDatas(data)
{
    if(!($.inArray(data, loadedDatas) !== -1)) {
        loadedDatas.push(data);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The functions are called like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //some others asynchrounous functions

        $.when(function1(), function2()).done(function3("test"));
    }

    ...

</script>
```

Comment: for your bonus question, why would you want to? the console is a much better place for that kind of info, unless you really want your end-user to see it.

Comment: Hmm, goal was to write in a <div> which function is exectued, but, well, I only have to overwritte the content of the div at the beginning of the function... I probably wanted to do something hard with .when() whereas it's really easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function1 and function2 must return promise objects for this to work. For example,

```
function function1 () {
    return $.ajax({...});
}
```

now you can use `$.when`

```
$.when(function1(),function2()).done(function3);
```

Edit: or:

```
$.when(function1(),function2()).done(function(){
    function3("test");
});
```

Comment: `function3()` is executed whereas `function1()` and `function2()` are not finished... For information, the ajax call look like `$.ajax(...).done();` there is no return.

Comment: there MUST be a return, otherwise it won't work. function1 and function2 MUST return a deferred or promise object. If they don't, and you cant modify them, and they don't have a callback, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Ok, so I have to return a `promise` object, but, 2 questions : Where do the Deferred must be declared ? As a global variable or in the function ? And do I have to `.resolve` it ? I just try both but it doesn't work, I probably forget something...

Comment: well, $.ajax() itself already returns a promise object, so if you simply did `return $.ajax(..` it would work.

Comment: I tried to `return $.ajax()` but `function3`, which displays something on the screen, is still exectued BEFORE `function1` and 2 are finished. Please look at my updated question.

Comment: That looks correct to me... Can you show where you used $.when?

Comment: remove `("test")`, if you want to be able to pass a param to that, you'll need to use an anonymous function there that executes function3.

Comment: I just monitored the beginning and the end of the three functions and it seems it's working, thank you very much ! Something is displayed before, but I thing the probelm is elsewhere and I will investigate to find what. Could you just please show me a example of what you call an "anonymous function there that execute function3 ?"

Comment: I've seen your update, I'll try this. Thanks again !