# Combine multiple calls to one Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Here is the situation: I have one JS file (getInfo.js) that contains a function with ajax.

```
define(["underscore", "jquery", "domReady!"],
function (_, $) {
return function (opUrl, opList, onCallback) {

        // IRRELEVANT CODE 

      self.getFetch = function (optionName) { ...
```

and multiple other JS files calls this function

```
var test = new getInfo(opUrl, opList, onCallback);
var getJuice = test.getfetch("DataStorage);
```

Is there a way to make these functions call from different JS file Asynchronous?
Or how can I make the getInfo.js script to wait for all the call to be done before fetching from ajax

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583345/call-multiple-functions-successively

Comment: I dont think so because the functions call are coming from different files